# How do I turn ON JSP error validation in eclipse Juno?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, eclipse-juno

I see many people asking how to turn off the validation, but I need the JSP validation turned on as we are getting bad code merges that go undetected in our system until run time.

I am using:

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
- Version: Juno Service Release 1
- Build id: 20120920-0800

I have followed the instructions on creating a new Dynamic Web Project, installing Tomcat, etc and still nothing... Is there a plugin out there that can help me maybe?

Answer (score 0):

- Select `Project` -> `Properties` -> `Validation` -> `Configure Workspace Settings`
- Select `JSP Syntax Validator`